# How to remove postgres 12 - Can't open /usr/share/postgresql-common/maintscripts-functions

Tags: 20.04, postgresql

Having some trouble deleting postgres 12 which has been causing lots of problems, like I can't run sudo apt upgrade at all because of that.

This is the error:

```
Setting up postgresql-client-12 (12.5-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-client-12.postinst: 7: .: Can't open /usr/share/postgresql-common/maintscripts-functions
dpkg: error processing package postgresql-client-12 (--configure):
 installed postgresql-client-12 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-client-12
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any ideas how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing removinig it through apt? To remove a package and associated config files through apt you can do

```
sudo apt remove --purge <package name>
```

If you want to just remove the package and keep associated files, you can just leave out the --purge flag, but it's often more useful to get rid of everything.

Comment: Yes, I have but no luck. But I managed to remove it eventually and I can't remember what I did to remove it! lol